# Issue with Foreach to Foreach C# MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, foreach

I have page which is show Order Details (salesLineInvoice) and under each Order details I should show Shipment details (SalesShipment) for again each Order details and there are no relation btw Order details and shipment details and then I decided have query for each of them ,which means one query for Order details Which is based on id to retrieve data for Order Details (This Part Working fine) and one Query for Shipment Details which is based on same id I mentioned before to retrieves Data for Shipment Details (I have so much problem with this part) and then in my View I did Foreach to Foreach , But I Cant figure out why the second Part Which is Shipment Details is not working . I mean i can see Ordre Details ,but nothing showed up for Shipment Details did I miss something ?! or should I use something else for this scenario like union or ..
Can someone help me or point me into right direction :)

Comment: There is a lot of extra info in there, so I'm just gonna take a shot in the dark for your issue. Use a For loop in your view, not a Foreach. Views need the items to be index accessible, which isn't possible in a Foreach.

Comment: When you say it is not working, are you saying anything inside the inner foreach is not rendering ? are you 100 % sure that your Where clause is valid and it is returning the correct data ? To make it simple and more readable, i would load the shipment detail of each order detail in the controller action itself so that my view does not need to do much C# code

Comment: @Shyju Foreach for Ordre Details is working fine and also where clause and i can see Ordre Details in browser 100% sure , but for Shipment Details  no nothing works and i cant see anything about Shipment Details in browser

Comment: @Shyju and sir would you please give me example with ,wat you said -> i would load the shipment detail of each order detail in the controller action itself so that my view does not need to do much C# code , so i can learn it :)

Comment: @mjwills i get red line under foreach > foreach statement cannot operate on variables of type 'int' because 'int' does not contain a public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: @gilliduck i would like give a try but , to be honest idont how for wokrs

Comment: @mjwills ops sorry , its able to render @Model.ShipmentDetailLineCloses.Where(p=>p.DocumentNoInvoice‌​O‌​rdreDeliveryClose == Field.DocumentSalesInvoice).ToList().Count . and in browser it show me 0 under each ordre Details

Comment: Please update your question with some (real) sample data for the tables involved, so we can have a look at how to possibly solve your underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach (var FieldShipment in Model.ShipmentDetailLineCloses
    .Where(p=>p.DocumentNoInvoiceOrdreDeliveryClose == Field.DocumentSalesInvoice).ToList())    
{
```

The code inside that `foreach` is not outputting anything since `Model.ShipmentDetailLineCloses.Where(p=>p.DocumentNoInvoiceOrdreDeliveryClose == Field.DocumentSalesInvoice).ToList()` is not returning any data (given you verified that `.Count` was 0). *Thus `foreach` works exactly as expected - there is no data in the `List` so it effectively does nothing.*

As such, you need to look into how `Model.ShipmentDetailLineCloses` is populated - since your problem is there and not in the view itself.

Comment: yes you right , but there is no relation btw Shipment Details and Ordre Details and its dosent matter which column i put to be id its not gonna work and talk with Ordre Details , so how should i show shipment Details for each ordre or how can i solve this

Comment: If there is no relation between the tables, and no reliable way to join them, then I think you are out of luck. But that is nothing to do with your `foreach`.

Comment: :(( yes u right , tnx for your help and your time , just last question , wat about i separate Shipment Details from Ordre Details Controller and view and make one for itself than can i related /associated with Ordre Details instead . do u think its possible though there is no relation!